# Advanced Redirect HTML

Tags: url

The follow URL, when inserted in Twitter, Facebook, etc, displays another destination, but when clicked, goes to another one. How to make that?

URL: http://isqua.work/new/hard/209

Answer (score 1):

The are a few ways to implement this.

1. Html - setting href different from the anchor text.

   `<a href="http://redirect.com">http://maskUrl.com</a>`
2. Redirect from the landing page via 301/2 redirect from the server. Example in php. This code should be hosted on maskUrl.com.

   header ("Location: http://redirect.com");
3. Redirect using javascript of the landing page.  This code is on maskUrl.com.

   window.location = "http://redirect.com";
4. I'm guessing what you are referring to, is tinyurl encoding.  Facebook probably registers the longer url to a database and assigns it a new shorter url.  tinyurl.com gives you an example.  You can enter a url in the box at the top and it returns an alternative url which redirects to the longer url.

Comment: Thank you but may I did not explain well. Please copy this url and past it on a facebook post and you will see a short description of website destination. BUT the resume automatically generated by Facebook from URL is from one website and when you click on link it send you to another different one!

Comment: Ok, then elaborate on what you did mean.

Comment: Edited comment above. Thank you.

Comment: @PLazzo See option 4 above.